# Proof that a the limit for this function is 1

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I'm stuck trying to prove that the function $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(-1,0)} \frac{\sin(x^3 + y^2 + 1)}{x^3 + y^2 + 1}=1$

I've tried using  $\sin(x) \le 1$, $\sin(x) \le x$ and others, but nothing I do seems to work

How do I prove this using epsilon-delta?

Comment: Are you going to prove it by definition?

Comment: I'm trying to, yes

Comment: HInt:$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (x_0,y_0)}f(x,y)=L\,$$
$$\forall \epsilon>0 \exists \delta >0:0<\sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2}<\delta \implies|f(x,y)-L|<\epsilon$$ are you try this?

Comment: I'm trying to make the norm appear somewhere but I'm failing at it

Comment: What is the difficulty? If $(x,y)$ is close to $(-1,0)$, then $x^3+y^2+1)$ is close to 0, and you know that $\frac{\sin z}{z}\to1$ as $z\to0$.

Answer (score 1):

Call $z=x^3+y^2+1$. Then you need to prove that $\lim_{z \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin z}{z}=1$.

Comment: I'm trying to use epsilon-delta

Comment: Beautiful technique!

Answer (score 0):

Take $\varepsilon>0$. Then, since $\lim_{x\to1}\frac{\sin x}x=1$, there is a $\delta^\ast>0$ such that$$\lvert x\rvert<\delta^*\implies\left\lvert\frac{\sin x}x-1\right\rvert<\varepsilon.$$On the other hand, you know that$$\lvert x^3+y^2+1\rvert=\bigl\lvert(x+1)(x^2-x+1)+y\bigr\rvert<3\lvert x+1\rvert+\lvert y\rvert$$if $\lvert x\rvert<1$. On the ither hand,$$3\lvert x+1\rvert+\lvert y\rvert<3\lVert(x+1,y)\rVert+\lVert(x+1,y)\rVert=4\bigl\lVert(x,y)-(-1,0)\bigr\rVert.$$So, take $\delta<1$ such that $\delta<\frac{\delta^\ast}4$  and then$$\bigl\lVert(x,y)-(-1,0)\bigr\rVert<\delta\implies\left\lvert\frac{\sin(x^3+y^2+1)}{x^3+y^2+1}-1\right\rvert<\varepsilon.$$

Comment: but does the identity for the sin(x) / x translate to multiple variable immediately?

Comment: If $x_0$ is such that $\left\lvert\frac{\sin x_0}{x_0}-1\right\rvert<\varepsilon$ and if $x^3+y^2+1=x_0$, then$$\left\lvert\frac{\sin(x^3+y^2+1)}{x^3+y^2+1}-1\right\rvert<\varepsilon.$$